# Event logging using log4Net or Enterprise Library

Tags: .net, events, logging

I have a legacy MVC application. I don't want to disturb all action methods but would like to log the user activity, along with series of methods invoked and the input parameter values passed and if at all any exceptions in this process. Is there a way i can do with minimal changes using .net reflection or any mvc filters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ActionFilterAttribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

If you're in .NET Core :

```
public class UserActivityFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutingDelegate next)
    {
        await next();
        // here get your logger service (example )
        var logger = context.HttpConcet.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ILogger)) as ILogDataOperations;
        await logger.LogUserActivity(context.HttpContext.User.Name, context.HttpContext.Request.Path);
    }

}
```

And put on your controller :

```
[Authorize]
[UserActivityFilter]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
...
}
```